# Express app deployed on cPanel not rendering Pug templates

Tags: node.js, deployment, godaddy-api

I have a NodeJS project using MongoDB and .pug templates. I deployed it on a VPS server with WHM and cPanel. After uploading the files through cPanel, I started the NodeJS app from the WHM terminal, and it successfully runs on port 80. However, when I visit my domain (domain.com), it shows an "index of" page instead of rendering my .pug templates.

Here's a simplified version of my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

// View engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

// Routes and other setup...

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

When I manually created an index.html file with "Hello" in it, it displays correctly at domain.com. But my project's .pug files are not rendering.

What could be the issue here? How can I get my Express app to render the .pug templates when accessing domain.com?

Comment: I solved problem RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^$ http://ip_adress:3000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ip_adress:3000/$1 [P,L]